# How to set different rate limits for different IPs in Nginx

Tags: api, nginx, rate-limiting

I am new to Nginx, and I am trying to use the `ngx_http_limit_req` Module in Nginx to  set different rate limits for different IPs in Nginx.

I know it is possible to set the same rate limit for all the IPs, as follows:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
```

However, for some IPs (for example `1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.7`), I want to set a different rate limit.

Anyone knows how to set this up in Nginx?

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/177461/how-to-rate-limit-in-nginx-but-including-excluding-certain-ip-addresses) might answer your question.